# Authentication problem when setting 2 apps in same project in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using 2 Android apps(react native) in one firebase project(Admin app and user app). I want to know how to setup google login  for both because they are using the same Firebase Authentication. 
In My case The user app is working fine. But on the admin app when iam try to login select account popup appear and after selecting account, on console, it shows and error "error: cancled"

Answer (score 0):

Just Add these two android project in the same firebase project. Then use the google login code in the login activity and don't use firebase import file in that activity.

Comment: kamaker In My case The user app is working fine. But on the admin app when iam try to login select account popup appear and after selecting account, on console, it shows and error "error: cancled"